# How to get a single javascript page using r.js

Tags: requirejs

I am doing my first try using requireJS and it works great !
I now would like to use the optimizer and i meet some issues when running my code in the browser.

I have these JS files:

- /public/javascripts/build.js
- /public/javascripts/main.js
- /public/javascripts/lib/jquery.min.js
- /public/javascripts/lib/require.min.js
- /public/javascripts/a.js
- /public/javascripts/b.js
- /public/javascripts/c.js

a.js, b.js and c.js are modules i define for my application using requireJS.

main.js:

```
require.config({
    paths: {
        'jQuery': 'lib/jquery.min.js'
    },
    shim: {
        'jQuery': {
            exports: '$'
        }
    }
});
require(['a.js'], function(A){
    var Entity = new A();
});
```

build.js

```
({
    baseUrl: ".",
    paths: {
        requireLib: "lib/require.min",
        jquery: "lib/jquery.min"
    },
    name: "main",
    out: "main-built.js",
    include: ["requireLib"]
})
```

Also i am wondering why do we have to specify the paths of the libraries into the build.js and not the other javascript files.

When i do not use the optimizer and only load the file 
`<script src="/javascripts/lib/require.min.js" data-main="/javascripts/main"></script>`
it works great, but when i run `r.js -o ./public/javascripts/build.js` and only load
`<script src="/javascripts/main-built.js"></script>` i get the error `Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function` in the minified code.

How to explain that ?

Here are the logs i get when running r.js

```
Tracing dependencies for: main
Uglifying file: /public/javascripts/main-built.js

/public/javascripts/main-built.js
----------------
/public/javascripts/lib/require.min.js
/public/javascripts/a.js
/public/javascripts/b.js
/public/javascripts/lib/jquery.min.js
/public/javascripts/c.js
/public/javascripts/main.js
```

Comment: The paths don't add up in your question. Just to mention one: the ``r.js`` trace shows the built file in ``/public/javascripts/main-built.js``. But you say you load it with ``<script src="/javascripts/lib/main-built.js"></script>``. Can you edit the question so that your paths are consistent? Also make sure that there is no typo. ``mains.js`` looks like a typo since everywhere else it is ``main``.

Comment: @Louis Thanks for the help, i have just hadded it ! About the `main-built.js` file it was just a mistake on Stack

Comment: Your paths still don't add up.

Comment: I have added all the paths from the files i use into my project directory, which paths do you still don't have ?

Comment: I think there is a language issue here. The phrase "your paths do not add up" means "your paths are not consistent." Your list of paths at the start of your question shows that the path to ``main.js`` is ``/public/javascripts/main.js`` but the output of ``r.js`` shows this path instead ``/javascripts/main.js``. This is a different path, not consistent with the first path.

Comment: That's right, sorry another mistake when reporting on Stack...

Comment: Hey Louis i just found the issue ! It was about the shim instruction !
When i drop it from the main, i get the same error including the multiple javascript files, so i tried to add it on the build.js and it works !
the "$" is undefined on the callback if i don't use it, do you know why ? I am working with jQuery 1.10

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I just have added

```
shim: {
    'jQuery': {
        exports: '$'
    }
}
```

into the build.js file, and it works perfectly !

Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

This is definitely wrong:

```
require(['a.js'], function(A){
    var Entity = new A();
});
```

You should not use extensions in the list of dependencies you give to `require` or `define`. Modules should be named without extension. So here `'a'`, not `'a.js'`. Using `'a.js'` will cause RequireJS to fail loading what you really want once the optimizer has run. Let's say you have a file named `a.js` which has:

```
define(function () {
    return function () {};
});
```

The optimizer will include it into your `main-built.js` file like this:

```
define("a", function () {
    return function () {};
});
```

Note how the first parameter to `define` is now `"a"`. This has been added by `r.js`. This is the name of the module. When you load `main-built.js`, a module named `"a"` is defined. When you use `require` with `"a.js"`, you are telling RequireJS you want something in a *file* named `a.js` so RequireJS will go looking for that and ignore what is in `main-built.js`.

Also, jQuery 1.8 or over does not need a shim.